# Nginx forwarding requests to the wrong Apache/Plesk Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

```
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  example.com localhost direct1.example.com www.example.com admin.example.com forum.example.com;

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/html;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Connection Close;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/html;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:80;
    }
}
```

This is what I have in nginx/defaults.conf. The server is currently using Apache fine, and Plesk, which seems to manage vhosts on its own (somehow).

Any requests to `example.com:81/media/image.jpg` work fine, but `example.com:81` uses an incorrect vhost.

I'm not 100% sure how the vhost situation works with Plesk, but it was installed and the default vhost is `server1.example.com`, and no matter how much fiddling with the proxy settings I do, I can't get it to use the `example.com` vhost.

**edit** added a `;` to the root line under location. It was missing, I tried adding it but still no luck.

**update** added `ServerName "example.com"` to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf`. Now under apache-status, it lists the vhost as example.com, but still "uses" server1.example.com. Boo.

It also seems that it's using DocumentRoot from the main apache httpd.conf, and not using the proper virtual host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [nginx docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) on `proxy_pass`:

> Note that the HTTP Host header is not forwarded, but is set based on
>   the proxy_pass statement.

This means your `proxy_set_header Host $host;` line has no effect. The actual Host header passed to Apache will be `Host: 127.0.0.1` as per the `proxy_pass` statement.

I recommend this `location /` section to proxy as you described:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Connection Close;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:80;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. So far that works. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: By default, nginx will use the proxy_pass argument for the Host header of the proxied request, but proxy_set_header Host $host; will override the default behavior and pass on the Host header from the original request.  The fact that this change is fixing the problem tells me that the vhosts weren't all set up to be available on 127.0.0.1 in apache.

Comment: despite the docs specifically saying you can't forward Host?

Comment: Despite the docs saying that the default is to use the proxy_pass argument.  You can override the default.

Comment: have you tested this personally? failed completely last time I tried to do it exactly how you said, as per the part of the docs saying you can't override the Host.

Comment: Yes I have, and I've recommended it to many other people in #nginx on freenode.  If you'd like to come there (or open a question here) showing what you attempted, I could try to figure out why it wasn't working for you.  What in the docs specifically says you can't override Host to you?  Because that needs to be changed.

Comment: the exact piece I pasted and linked :) "Note that the HTTP Host header is not forwarded, but is set based on the proxy_pass statement."

Comment: That doesn't say it can't be overridden.  I'll try to make that clearer.

Comment: The semantics say, rather than "you can't override Host", that proxy_pass itself overrides it (because proxy_pass is the last module being resolved).